# Import all tables from MySQL to Hive. What is wrong with my command?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

Is there anything wrong with the below command. Its not working for me.

```
sqoop import-all-tables 
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username=retail_dba 
-- compression-codec=snappy 
--as-parquetfile --hive-import -m 1

16/08/17 08:34:07 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/08/17 08:34:07 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: 
Using Hive-specific delimiters   for output. You can override
16/08/17 08:34:07 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: 
delimiters with --fields- terminated-by, etc.
16/08/17 08:34:08 INFO manager.MySQLManager: 
Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/08/17 08:34:08 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/08/17 08:34:08 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop:
Got exception running Sqoop:  
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Could you add the `--verbose` option to the command and show the complete log message?

Comment: @JaimeCr That is the whole error message i got even after adding                    `-- verbose`

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the complete error you are getting? 
Does you error contain - Class not found exception? If yes, go to $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop find mapred-site.xml and change/add the value of property mapreduce.framework.name as yarn. Save the file and restart hadoop

Comment: when you need more input about question leave a comment on post. Once you have full clarity about problem then provide answer.

Comment: @Sridhar did you try the above solution?